# Verilog 3 bit concentrate of 2 variables

Tags: verilog

I am Trying to understand this bit of Verilog code..

```
reg [2:0] SYNC;
always @(posedge clk) SYNC <= {SYNC[1:0], ASYNC};
wire SYNC_risingedge = (SYNC[2:1] == 2'b01);
wire SYNC_fallingedge = (SYNC[2:1] == 2'b10);
wire SYNC_on = ~SYNC[1];
```

From what i understand. 
A 3 bit reg is made (sync)
When the clock rises, sync is equal to the combination of bits 1 and 0 with the current value of (async).
The  SYNC_risingedge is equal to (sync) bits 2 and 1 and the value of binary '01'
The  SYNC_fallingedge is equal to (sync) bits 2 and 1 and the value of binary '10'
The SYNC_on is equal to the inverse of sync.

My questions are next to the lines in quotes.

```
reg [2:0] SYNC;
always @(posedge clk) SYNC <= {SYNC[1:0], ASYNC}; *"does this mean that it concentrates         the state of ASYNC with only bits 1 and 0?"*
wire SYNC_risingedge = (SYNC[2:1] == 2'b01); *"is the binary number 01 placed only in  bits 2 and 1? if so, how does it affect the previous line?"*
wire SYNC_fallingedge = (SYNC[2:1] == 2'b10); *"same question as previous line"*
wire SYNC_on = ~SYNC[1]; *"What does the [1] mean in ~SYNC[1]?"*
```

I've scoured the web, looking for Verilog syntax to understand this bit of code, but have come up short. 
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Question 1

   > ```
   > always @(posedge clk) SYNC <= {SYNC[1:0], ASYNC};
   > ```
   >
   > does this mean that it concentrates the state of ASYNC with only bits 1 and 0?

   I think you mean "concatenates", and you're about right, yes.  This statement essentially left-shifts `SYNC` by 1 and then puts the value of `ASYNC` in bit 0.  This shifting operation takes place on each rising clock edge.

   Complete table:

   ```
      SYNC  |   ASYNC   |  New SYNC Setting
   ---------+-----------|--------------------
      000   |     0     |       000
      001   |     0     |       010
      010   |     0     |       100
      011   |     0     |       110
      100   |     0     |       000
      101   |     0     |       010
      110   |     0     |       100
      111   |     0     |       110
      000   |     1     |       001
      001   |     1     |       011
      010   |     1     |       101
      011   |     1     |       111
      100   |     1     |       001
      101   |     1     |       011
      110   |     1     |       101
      111   |     1     |       111
   ```
2. Question 2

   > ```
   > wire SYNC_risingedge = (SYNC[2:1] == 2'b01);
   > ```
   >
   > is the binary number 01 placed only in  bits 2 and 1? if so, how does it affect the previous line?

   No, the `==` is a *test*, not an assignment.  If those two bits of SYNC match `2b'01`, then the `SYNC_risingedge` wire will be high.  Otherwise it will be low.

   Note:  the "assignment" to `SYNC_risingedge` is asynchronous - it's just combinational logic.
3. Question 3

   > ```
   > wire SYNC_fallingedge = (SYNC[2:1] == 2'b10);
   > ```
   >
   > same question as previous line

   Same answer, too.
4. Question 4

   > ```
   > wire SYNC_on = ~SYNC[1];
   > ```
   >
   > What does the [1] mean in ~SYNC[1]?

   It's just referring to bit 1 of `SYNC`.  SYNC_on is high whenever SYNC[1] is low, and vice versa.